# New Trello User - Sign Up with Company UNIX ID email or lastName.firstName Email?

Tags: trello-organization

We're just starting to use Trello at our company. I'm wondering if it would be worth the effort to standardize the email address for our Trello session. For example, my UNIX ID is john15@company.com whereas my regular email is smith.john@company.com. Does standardizing enhance some Trello features, like grouping people by their last names or finding individuals, etc?